# Edges of SVG appearing blurry when viewed in mobile

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I am using a SVG instead of an actual emoji in my website to make sure that it looks the same on all devices. However, the edges of the SVG are appearing blurry and pixelated when I view it on my iPhone. (does not happen on desktop.)

[image: svg]
[image: svg 2]

As you can see from the first image (✌️emoji svg), some parts of the SVG are blurry while others are crisp. In the second svg, (emoji) the edges are completely blurry.
It is not the svg that is causing the blurriness, it appears completely crisp on desktop.
This is how I am inserting the svg:

```
 .emoji {
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:1em 1em;
    display:inline-block;
    height:1em;
    margin:0 .05em 0 .1em;
    vertical-align:-0.1em;
    width:1em
}
.emoji.victory-hand {
    background-image: url(../emojis/emoji/victory_hand_color_default.svg);
}
.emoji.thought-balloon {
    background-image: url(../emojis/emoji/thought_balloon_color.svg);
}
```

```
<h2>hello<i class="emoji victory-hand"></i></h2>
<h2>projects <i class="emoji thought-balloon"></i></h2>
```

The svg is fine when I use an svg viewer to view it or use a computer, it only appears blurry on mobile. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: open the svg file with a web browser ... does it still look pixelated?

Comment: Nope, the svg is perfectly fine when I open it or use a svg viewer

Comment: My question was if anyone knew why this was happening or if there is a solution, sorry if I did not make it clear in the post

Comment: your post does not say anything like that ... please edit your post

Comment: Can you share one of these emoji svgs? I've experienced similar issues with highly complex svg images - in particular if they contain `<mask>`s. Apparently iOs safari's renderer tries to optimize rendering times by rasterizing small images at a fixed resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, iOS safari apparently renders **masked images at a fixed resolution**.
So the image gets blurry when zooming in.

That's probably the reason, why some contours in the OP's emoji are crisp while others are blurry/pixelated.

[image: safari pixelated emoji rendering]
Left: masked shape; right: clipped shape

```css
body {
  font-size: 5em;
  background: #000;
}

svg {
  height: 100%
}

.icon-wrap {
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000"></rect>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M62.05 7.31c6.86 0 14.13 6.46 14.41 12.79c0.21 4.74-1.42 10.5-3 16.07c-1.98 6.98-3.68 13.01-2.02 17.42a3 3 0 0 0 2.81 1.94h0.11l7.2-0.25h0.06c7.33 0 13.3 5.96 13.31 13.3l0.05 42.21c0 2.5-0.97 4.86-2.74 6.63s-4.12 2.75-6.63 2.75h-0.08c-8.6-0.07-21.51-0.41-34.19-1.6c-8.6-0.81-17.48-2.09-24.11-5.85c-2.2-1.25-4.58-1.54-6.49-1.78c-0.76-0.09-1.47-0.18-2.03-0.32c-4.2-0.99-7.14-4.61-7.15-8.8l-0.08-32.75c-0.01-3.78 2.69-6.95 6.42-7.53c0.15-0.02 0.31-0.06 0.45-0.11c0.56-0.18 13.94-4.55 24.05-12.45c4.87-3.81 9.05-9.67 11.17-15.68s2.1-12.36 2.09-17.5c0-2.44-0.01-5.74 0.41-6.74a10.97 10.97 0 0 1 5.98-1.75"></path>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <radialGradient id="a" cx="51.77" cy="31.401" r="87.039" gradientTransform="matrix(-.00218 1 -.7873 -.00172 76.604 -20.315)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#FFCA28" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFB300" />
    </radialGradient>
    <path mask="url(#mask)" fill="url(#a)" d="M85.52 121.67c-8.63-.07-21.58-.41-34.32-1.61-8.77-.83-17.83-2.14-24.71-6.04-1.94-1.1-4.06-1.37-5.94-1.6-.8-.1-1.55-.19-2.19-.34-4.88-1.15-8.29-5.37-8.31-10.26l-.07-32.75c-.01-4.53 3.22-8.32 7.69-9.02.08-.01.15-.03.23-.05.55-.18 13.69-4.46 23.59-12.2 4.66-3.64 8.65-9.25 10.68-15 2.02-5.73 2.01-11.98 2-17 0-3.24-.01-7.27.87-7.86 2.14-1.41 4.5-2.13 7.01-2.13 7.72 0 15.6 7.05 15.91 14.23.22 4.98-1.45 10.86-3.06 16.54-1.9 6.73-3.55 12.54-2.06 16.49.22.59.78.97 1.4.97l7.29-.25h.07c8.16 0 14.8 6.64 14.81 14.79l.05 42.21c0 2.91-1.12 5.64-3.18 7.69a10.81 10.81 0 01-7.69 3.19h-.07z" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div class="icon-wrap">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="clip">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000"></rect>
        <path fill="#fff" d="M62.05 7.31c6.86 0 14.13 6.46 14.41 12.79c0.21 4.74-1.42 10.5-3 16.07c-1.98 6.98-3.68 13.01-2.02 17.42a3 3 0 0 0 2.81 1.94h0.11l7.2-0.25h0.06c7.33 0 13.3 5.96 13.31 13.3l0.05 42.21c0 2.5-0.97 4.86-2.74 6.63s-4.12 2.75-6.63 2.75h-0.08c-8.6-0.07-21.51-0.41-34.19-1.6c-8.6-0.81-17.48-2.09-24.11-5.85c-2.2-1.25-4.58-1.54-6.49-1.78c-0.76-0.09-1.47-0.18-2.03-0.32c-4.2-0.99-7.14-4.61-7.15-8.8l-0.08-32.75c-0.01-3.78 2.69-6.95 6.42-7.53c0.15-0.02 0.31-0.06 0.45-0.11c0.56-0.18 13.94-4.55 24.05-12.45c4.87-3.81 9.05-9.67 11.17-15.68s2.1-12.36 2.09-17.5c0-2.44-0.01-5.74 0.41-6.74a10.97 10.97 0 0 1 5.98-1.75"></path>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <radialGradient id="a" cx="51.77" cy="31.401" r="87.039" gradientTransform="matrix(-.00218 1 -.7873 -.00172 76.604 -20.315)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset=".6" stop-color="#FFCA28" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFB300" />
    </radialGradient>
    <path clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="url(#a)" d="M85.52 121.67c-8.63-.07-21.58-.41-34.32-1.61-8.77-.83-17.83-2.14-24.71-6.04-1.94-1.1-4.06-1.37-5.94-1.6-.8-.1-1.55-.19-2.19-.34-4.88-1.15-8.29-5.37-8.31-10.26l-.07-32.75c-.01-4.53 3.22-8.32 7.69-9.02.08-.01.15-.03.23-.05.55-.18 13.69-4.46 23.59-12.2 4.66-3.64 8.65-9.25 10.68-15 2.02-5.73 2.01-11.98 2-17 0-3.24-.01-7.27.87-7.86 2.14-1.41 4.5-2.13 7.01-2.13 7.72 0 15.6 7.05 15.91 14.23.22 4.98-1.45 10.86-3.06 16.54-1.9 6.73-3.55 12.54-2.06 16.49.22.59.78.97 1.4.97l7.29-.25h.07c8.16 0 14.8 6.64 14.81 14.79l.05 42.21c0 2.91-1.12 5.64-3.18 7.69a10.81 10.81 0 01-7.69 3.19h-.07z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

#### Workarounds:

- replace `<mask>` with `<clipPath>`
- use compound paths for cutout shapes like holes (e.g. in the letter O)
- try another emoji library with a more simplistic/cleaner svg structure

Answer (score -1):

Safari has this really big issue where svgs are not rendered properly for its device's retina display.

Try adding:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

To the svg.

If not, it might not be fixable as any svgs in Safari do not work well with outlines.

Also try adding:

```
shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"
```

To the svg.

Instead if that does not work either try:

```
shape-rendering = "crispEdges"
```

Instead of geometricPrecision, that disables anti-aliasing on the image through the browser.

Comment: hmm, when I added -webkit-transform too the css the svg just disappeared and the shape-rendering=“geometricPrecision” didn’t seem to do anything. Also, the svg appears blurry on the chrome mobile app too

Comment: So it's not a safari thing. It's an IPhone thing. See my edit.

Comment: Don't use -webkit-transform then. Sorry for the mishap. In my edit, I also added crispEdges, try that too.

Comment: Actually iOs will always use the safari renderer even for firefox or chrome. Not sure if it also applies to iPadOs.